# jquery mobile - detecting touches array on swipe event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe, touch-event

I'm using jquery mobile for it's swipe detection on touch screens. I want to listen for a `swipe` event, but only do something if more than one finger is touching the screen. I know with normal touch events this can be detected via the `touches` array within the event, but this doesn't seem to exist when I check within the event after `swipe` is fired. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I could access the `touches` array after a `swipe` event is fired?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it wasn't jquery mobile I should be overriding, but the slideshow plugin I was using (jquery cycle2). Here's my code I came up with:

```js
window.global_touches = null;

$('.page').on({
    touchstart: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.global_touches = e.originalEvent.touches;
    },
    touchmove: function(e) {
      window.global_touches = e.originalEvent.touches;
    },
    touchend: function(e) {
      window.global_touches = e.originalEvent.touches;
    },
    touchcancel: function(e) {
      window.global_touches = e.originalEvent.touches;
      clearHighlight();
    }
});

$('.inner-slideshow').on('cycle-bootstrap', function(e, optionHash, API) {
    API.origAdvanceSlide = API.advanceSlide;
    API.advanceSlide = function(numberOfPositions) {
        if (window.global_touches && window.global_touches.length >= 2) {
           API.origAdvanceSlide.call(API, numberOfPositions);
        }
    };
});
```